# How to write unit test for shell script present in groovy

Tags: java, shell, unit-testing, groovy, junit

I have a groovy method which has shell script code which executes inside a groovy class. I need to write a unit test to validate the method. I really have no idea on how to write unit test for this scenario.

@Override

```
void addTag(String tagName){
    steps.sh(script:'''
    lastTag=$(git tag | grep "^[0-9].^*" | tail -1)
    echo "lasttag: $lastTag"
    if [[ $lastTag == "" ]]
    then
      changeLog=$(git log origin/$BRANCH_NAME --pretty=format:"%h - %ce(%cn), %ar : %s")
      git tag -a ''' + tagName + ''' -m "Changelog" -m "$changeLog"
    else
      echo "Previous Version: $lastTag"
      changeLog=$(git log origin/$BRANCH_NAME...refs/tags/$lastTag --pretty=format:"%h - %ce(%cn), %ar : %s")
      git tag -a ''' + tagName + ''' -m "Changelog" -m "$changeLog"
    fi''', returnStatus: true)
}
```

Can anyone provide some idea ?

Comment: short answer you cannot.  Try converting your shell script into "jgit" code.  That will help to test better (even then you need mocking ) or a dummy git repo for testing